# assign value of arbitrary line in 2-d array to nans

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array, z,  in which I would like to assign values to nan based on the equation of a line +/- a width of 20. I am trying to implement the Raman 2nd scattering correction as it is done by the eem_remove_scattering method in the eemR package listed here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eemR/vignettes/introduction.html 
but the method isn't visible.

```
   import numpy as np
   ex = np.array([240, 245, 250, 255, 260, 265, 270, 275, 280, 285, 290, 295, 300,
        305, 310, 315, 320, 325, 330, 335, 340, 345, 350, 355, 360, 365,
        370, 375, 380, 385, 390, 395, 400, 405, 410, 415, 420, 425, 430,
        435, 440, 445, 450])
   em = np.array([300, 302, 304, 306, 308, 310, 312, 314, 316, 318, 320, 322, 324,
        326, 328, 330, 332, 334, 336, 338, 340, 342, 344, 346, 348, 350,
        352, 354, 356, 358, 360, 362, 364, 366, 368, 370, 372, 374, 376,
        378, 380, 382, 384, 386, 388, 390, 392, 394, 396, 398, 400, 402,
        404, 406, 408, 410, 412, 414, 416, 418, 420, 422, 424, 426, 428,
        430, 432, 434, 436, 438, 440, 442, 444, 446, 448, 450, 452, 454,
        456, 458, 460, 462, 464, 466, 468, 470, 472, 474, 476, 478, 480,
        482, 484, 486, 488, 490, 492, 494, 496, 498, 500, 502, 504, 506,
        508, 510, 512, 514, 516, 518, 520, 522, 524, 526, 528, 530, 532,
        534, 536, 538, 540, 542, 544, 546, 548, 550, 552, 554, 556, 558,
        560, 562, 564, 566, 568, 570, 572, 574, 576, 578, 580, 582, 584,
        586, 588, 590, 592, 594, 596, 598, 600])
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(ex, em)
    z = np.sin(X) + np.cos(Y)
```

The equation that I would like to apply is em = - 2 ex/ (0.00036*ex-1) + 500.
I want to set every value in the array that intersects this line (+/- 20 ) to be set to nans. Its simple enough to set a single element to nans, but I havent been able to locate a python function to apply this equation to the array and only set values that intersect with this line to nans.
The desired output would be a new array with the same dimensions as z, but with the values that intersect the line equivalent to nan. Any suggestions on how to proceed are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.where` in the form `np.where( "condition for intersection", np.nan, z)`:

```
zi = np.where( np.abs(-2*X/(0.00036*X-1) + 500 - Y) <= 20, np.nan, z)
```

As a matter of fact, there are no intersections here because (0.00036*ex-1) is close to -1 for all your values, which makes `- 2*ex/(0.00036*ex-1)` close to `2*ex`, and adding 500 brings this over any values you have in `em`. But in principle this works.

Also, I suspect that the goal you plan to achieve by setting those values to NaN would be better achieved by using a [masked array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html).